# Regex - Match a sentence but ignoring certian words if present

Tags: regex

I am a complete newbie re Regex and I am trying to create a single expression that will find both of these sentences..

400 people drive dark blue cars

400 people drive cars

So the 'dark blue' is ignored if there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by either using an alternation or an optional group:

With alternation (https://regex101.com/r/qIjNWF/1):

```
400 people drive dark blue cars|400 people drive cars
```

The pipe symbol is working like a logical OR resp. alternation. So, it matches either the left side or the right side.

With an optional group (https://regex101.com/r/p5Z7eU/1/):

```
400 people drive (dark blue )?cars
```

The braces are grouping an expression and the question mark is marking this group as optional. A group is also being captured to be referenced again. If you don't need that you can also use non-capturing groups:

```
400 people drive (?:dark blue )?cars
```

Comment: Thank you - I was using TRegExpr in my Delphi 7 app but it produced a modifier error. So I switched to TPerlRegex and it worked correctly.